# List of a lists in R using an index

Tags: r, list, syntax

I want to add a list as an element of another list in R.  This appears possible, but I do not know the syntax.  I have tried multiple different things, and have come up with the following four examples to illustrate the issue.

My goal is to get something close to example 3, where I can write a statement similar to: `a$b[5]$c = 7`.

### Example #1

```
> q = list()
```

```
> q[1] = list(1,2)
Warning message:
In q[1] = list(1, 2) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

### Example #2:

```
> a = list()
> a$b = list()
> a$b[1] = list()
> a$b[2] = list(1)
```

```
> a$b[3] = list(1,2)
Warning message:
In a$b[3] = list(1, 2) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

### Example #3:

```
> a$b[5]$c = 7
Warning message:
In a$b[5]$c = 7 :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

### Example #4:

#### Part #1

```
> w = list("1"=list(1,1), "2"=list(2,2))
```

```
> w
$`1`
$`1`[[1]]
[1] 1

$`1`[[2]]
[1] 1


$`2`
$`2`[[1]]
[1] 2

$`2`[[2]]
[1] 2
```

#### Part #2

```
> w[1] = 5
```

```
> w
$`1`
[1] 5

$`2`
$`2`[[1]]
[1] 2

$`2`[[2]]
[1] 2
```

Comment: Use double brackets: `q[[1]] = list(1, 2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @[Rohit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1763250/rohit) said, using double brackets works.  This solves the question by allowing the following operations:

```
> a = list()
> a$b = list()
> a$b[[10]] = list(1,2)
> a$b[[5]] = list(1,2,3)
> a$b[[4]] = 0
> a$b[[3]] = list()
> a$b[[3]]$c = 0
> a$b[[20]] = 5
> a$b[[30]] = list()
> a$b[[40]] = list(1,2)
> a$b[[50]] = list()
> a$b[[50]]$c = list()
> a$b[[50]]$b = 5
> a$b[[50]]$k = list()
> a$b[[50]]$k[1] = list()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is often being done behind the scenes in the lattice package and the function used is `modifyList`. Here's the help page examples. I don't think this function  accomplishes assignment to numbered elements within sublists, however. It is only defined for named lists.

```
 ?modifyList
 foo <- list(a = 1, b = list(c = "a", d = FALSE))
 bar <- modifyList(foo, list(e = 2, b = list(d = TRUE)))
 str(foo)
#------
List of 2
 $ a: num 1
 $ b:List of 2
  ..$ c: chr "a"
  ..$ d: logi FALSE
#-------
 str(bar)
#----
List of 3
 $ a: num 1
 $ b:List of 2
  ..$ c: chr "a"
  ..$ d: logi TRUE
 $ e: num 2
#--------
```